# Remove value duplicate array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and need to remove if it is with the value of the `from [id]` duplicate item, I tried to do with:

```
$comments_new = array_map ("unserialize", 
          array_unique (array_map ("serialize", $ comments)))
```

But, there is no change.Template of my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [created_time] => 2018-10-28T17:35:58+0000
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Usuario
                    [id] => 111111
                )

            [message] =>test  as das
            [id] => 4234234214123412341234124
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [created_time] => 2018-10-28T17:35:24+0000
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Usuario2
                    [id] => 22222222
                )

            [message] => test
            [id] => 12341241234134444343
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [created_time] => 2018-10-28T18:44:08+0000
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Usuario3
                    [id] => 33333333
                )

            [message] => ccccc
            [id] => 223423421243123412341234123
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [created_time] => 2018-10-28T18:43:44+0000
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Usuario2
                    [id] => 22222222
                )

            [message] => test other
            [id] => 23424123412341234
        )


)
```

Note that inside the array there is the `ID` item, it is for this item that it must be checked if it is duplicated, then I must remove the record from the array.

Comment: Can you show briefly what you would expect as the output (only for the duplicated items) (i.e. do you want the first or last of the duplicate items)

Comment: @sNniffer May I ask why you prefer an overcomplicated answer which is O(n²) instead of O(1)? An example on my local machine with 20,000 comments having random IDs between 0 and 20,000 on PHP 5.4 showed 34 milliseconds (my four lines) vs. 11 minutes (accepted answer), and takes more memory.) See example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83d11b22c9cf2be9f2a488b4b1f6dbd34c82daca

Comment: @steffen your solution is O(n), while the accepted solution is O(n²). The accepted answer can also handle multiple criteria which is something that indexing by a single value cannot achieve in a reliable way. The accepted answer is the general solution for de-duplication by any criteria.

Comment: @RalphRitoch Yes, sorry I meant O(n). I however think that your solution might be practical in some cases, but certainly not here where the question is very specific on the criteria. Removing duplicates which share the same ID - that's implemented in 5 seconds and extremely fast. I also disagree on you saying it's the "general solution for deduplication". Actually most implementations in modern languages implement a set of objects without duplicates by mapping these objects to integers (=hashes). I've been well aware of all the things you've commented when I wrote my answer and read yours.

Comment: @steffen than you also know hashes are prone to collisions but yes, a solution is possible in o(n) by generating hashes but than you run the risk of collisions.

Comment: @RalphRitoch You simply guarantee that there are no collisions: Fortunately PHP supports unlimited length array keys, so that's pretty easy. (Btw - PHP will internally calculate hashes for the keys and do all collision handling for you.) But we're losing scope here. The specific solution to the question is indexing.

Comment: @steffen indexing is an optimization (in some cases) and it isn't the only solution. If you are looking for a functional solution without side-effects than my solution is correct. I clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functional solution using `array_reduce` and `array_filter` which has no side effects.

Replace `$arr_in` with the variable containing your data, and you can replace the code following `// Check if keys match` with any rule you need for considering records a duplicate.

```
$arr_out = array_reduce ( 
    $arr_in, // Input Array
    function($out,$item) { 
        return 
            count(
                array_filter(
                    $out,
                    function($e) use(&$item) {
                        // Check if keys match
                        return $e["from"]["id"] == $item["from"]["id"]; 
                    }
                )
            ) > 0 ? 
            $out : 
            array_merge($out,array($item)); 
    }, 
    array() 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, use array_filter:

```
<?php
$comment = [
    [
        "created_time" => new DateTime(),
        "from" => [
            "name" => "test1",
            "id" => 1
        ],
        "message" => "test1",
        "id" => 4234234214123412341234124
    ],
    [
        "created_time" => new DateTime(),
        "from" => [
            "name" => "test2",
            "id" => 1
        ],
        "message" => "test2",
        "id" => 17481419471248
    ]
];
$temp = array();
$comment = array_filter($comment, function ($v) use (&$temp) {
    if (in_array($v['from']['id'], $temp)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        array_push($temp, $v['from']['id']);
        return true;
    }
});

var_dump($comment);
```

Comment: Don't use `in_array`, that'll result in bad performance. Just `$temp['from']['id'] = true` and then `isset($temp['from']['id'])`. Or in short: `return !isset($temp['from']['id']) ? !($temp['from']['id'] = 1) : true;`

Comment: @steffen this solution is actually better than yours because it can handle object keys.

Comment: This solution can't easily handle multiple keys but using count(array_filter()) > 0 in place of in_array() such as in my solution can resolve that small issue. This solution is also o(n²) as in_array is o(n) * o(n) of the array_filter()

Answer (score 0):

Just index it:

```
foreach ($comments as $el) {
    $temp[$el['from']['id']] = $el;
}
$comments = array_values($temp);
```

Comment: This solution cannot handle multiple criteria. For example if a record with the same number of child elements and two matching fields determines a duplicate such as $a["k1"] == $b["k1"] && $a["k2"] == $b["k2"] && (count($a["children"]) == count($b["children"]) ) than using an associative array isn't going to solve the problem. Your solution only works for a single key, and only if that key isn't an object.

Comment: @RalphRitoch I'm sorry, but you are wrong here. This solution is capable handling multiple criteria. Calculating a key by more data, even with `serialize()` or `json_encode()`, is still O(n) and so the preferable solution. Try the benchmark if you don't believe it.

Comment: your solution doesn't use serialize though so it will crash on object keys. As for benchmarking, I know the difference between O(n) and O(n²). The serialize() may be a good optimization but it isn't clear code. Using my solution its easy to make a functional function out of it which accepts the array and a matcher function making it a general function for any case.